# How to retrieve Members under manager using Microsoft Graph using .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I am pretty new to C# and I'm trying to get List directReports under a manager who has logged in and authenticated with AAD. (GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/directReports) to get Alias name.

Thanks

ps. I am using ASP.NET MVC and this is the doc I am following

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post what code you have in your current attempt and we will be of much more help to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are struggling with how to make requests against the API, I would recommend using the GraphServiceClient nuget package, we use it and it is pretty good:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet

There are pretty good instructions in the README. You probably want something like this:

```
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
    requestMessage
        .Headers
        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}));

var directReports = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].DirectReports.Request().GetAsync();
foreach (var directReport in directReports)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This makes it much easy to make HTTP request to the API

Answer (score 2):

You might want to see the reference documentation for directReports: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0

Also to get a token to acces the graph, you'll find the following sample (Web App calling Grap) very close to what you want to achieve: [aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph)

See [HomeController.cs#L41-L64](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/238d68bd9847a49bb59d0868a15f30af48519d6c/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L41-L64)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Contact()
{
 var scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
 try
 {
  var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(HttpContext, scopes);
   CallGraphApiOnBehalfOfUser(accessToken);
   ...
  }
 }
```